# When should I call removeObserver:forKeyPath from within a closing ViewController class that is observing a persistant Model class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, memory-management, key-value-observing

I have a `ViewController` class that has a property that is the model which I want to observe as properties on the model change.  Within my model object I have a property that is periodically updated in the background of my application.  As it updates, I need to execute code within my `ViewController`.

To do this, I create an observer on my model from within my `ViewController` `viewDidLoad` method.

```
[ModelObject addObserver:self 
              forKeyPath:@"State" 
                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                 context:nil];
```

As you can see, this is nothing special and the observation method behaves as it should so long as I leave the view displayed on my screen.  If I remove the above view from the parent view, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error message when my `ModelObject` instance `Mode` property changes.  Specifically, my app crashes at the line that is updating the `Mode` property and I receive the mostly useless `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the following line of code within the ModelObject instance.

```
//This is located in a method that periodically toggles the value of "State"
[self setState: 2];
```

I would assume the solution to this problem is to call `[ModelObject removeObserver: self forKeyPath:@"State"]` from somewhere within my `ViewController` when it is removed from it's parent subview array.  However, I have added that line of code within my `viewDidUnload` method but I've found the the `viewDidUnload` method isn't being called.  I'm not sure if that is the right place, but it needs to go some where.

What might I be doing incorrectly?  I know the problem is KVO related because if I remove the observation, the application works without any problem.  My model instance can toggle this value as much as it wants and my application never crashes.  What should I do to be sure that my observer is removed correctly when the observing view is being removed from it's parent's subview array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I generally like to put the `addObserver:` and `removeObserver:` in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:`. I find these are more reliable bookends than `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: I second this solution. `viewDidUnload:` is called when a memory warning is received and does not correspond to `viewDidLoad:` like one may think.

Comment: This is problematic when unit-testing a view controller without adding it to a view hierarchy.

Comment: I would recommend calling the viewWillAppear:/DidAppear:/etc. methods as part of the unit test. I'd recommend making that a part of unit testing any VC since these are critical life-cycle methods that your VC needs to respond to correctly.
(That said, I generally focus my unit testing outside of the VC. I'm not saying testing the VC is bad; I'm just saying I personally focus on the model in unit test.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer @RobNapier, great to see answers from authoritative developers.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove it in the view controller's -dealloc

Comment: You should only do this if you added yourself as an observer at object creation (`init...` and `awakeFromNib`). Otherwise you can get an imbalance. For example, `viewDidLoad` can be called many more times than `dealloc`.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely true, and that's always how I do it.